# How to implement Admob Native ads in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob

I tried following the tutorials from google but things are just not working out. I am having error in my RecyclerViewAdapter.

Error is as follows 
RecyclerViewAdapter. (commented in 9th line)

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {

int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

switch (viewType){

    case AD_VIEW_TYPE:
        NativeExpressAdViewHolder nativeExpressHolder = (NativeExpressAdViewHolder)holder;
        NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView)arrayList.get(Position); //Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'app.modals.cardSetterGetter' to 'com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView

        ViewGroup adCardView = (ViewGroup)nativeExpressHolder.itemView;
        adCardView.removeAllViews();

        if(adView.getParent() != null){
            ((ViewGroup)adView.getParent()).removeView(adView);
        }

        adCardView.addView(adView);
        break;

    case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:

    default:
        String card_image;
        CardSetterGetter cardSetterGetter;
        cardSetterGetter = arrayList.get(position);

        card_image = constants.SERVERIP.concat(cardSetterGetter.getImageurl());
        holder.cardSetterGetter = cardSetterGetter;
        holder.title.setText(cardSetterGetter.getImagetitle()); //set title

        cardSetterGetter.getTag();

        PointF focusPoint = new PointF(0.5f, 0f);
        // your app populates the focus point

        holder.image // set image
                .getHierarchy()
                .setActualImageFocusPoint(focusPoint);
        holder.image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(card_image));
}

}
```

Comment: please, add your implementation for method `getItemViewType(position)` and declaration and initialisation for `arrayList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should not add Views to `listItems`.
   `listItems` contains items, not views.
2. `NativeExpressAdViewHolder` should extend `RecyclerViewHolder`.
3. `holder.getPosition()` is a position, not an adView. It can't be cast to `NativeExpressAdView`.
4. If you still want to keep adViews in items list, you should change type of itemsList as it is described in example. `private final List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems;`

not `List<app.appname.CardSetterGetter>`

Comment: for full code and the tutorial I was following, you can look at my previous question about same issue here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140421/error-incompatible-types-while-adding-nativeads-in-recyclerview)

Comment: ViewHolders are for holding Views. It is not great idea (as I see) to hold Views in items list. Moreover, Admob is quite poor coded and each AdView creates a lot of threads... But, yes, you can keep you views in items list...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your second and third point helped me solve two issues.. Please elaborate on third one. Where should I add Views if not in listItems.

Comment: items list is facing the same issue. Should I show you more of the code in fragment?

Comment: I ended up creating a Singletone AdKeeper object that keeps, loads and reloads ads. And ViewHodler takes an AdView from that keeper in onBindViewHolder(). And then releases when it is not needed. Quite a bicycle.

Comment: Yes, sow me please `private List listItems` declaration and initialisation.

Comment: hey, i edited the question. thanks for solving two issues.. I understand this issue but don't know how to quite solve it.